# What are the reaction rate constants, or coefficients, of coal combustion at high temperature?

Tags: kinetics, reaction-control, rate-equation

Say I have coal that I will combust with $\ce{O2}$ at a high temperature of $\pu{1600-1800 K}$, what are the reaction rate constants, or coefficients, of the main reactions?

I have searched around literature, but it seems the constant increases exponentially depending on the temperature. However, I cannot find any research on some experimentally found rate constant at a temperature above 500 kelvin.

Comment: And you found some for lower temperatures?

Comment: Heterogenous reaction rates are very, very tricky. Surface geometry and matter transport is not something I would want to theoretically analyze.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, see:  Liu et. al., 2022: Oxidation reaction constants for coal spontaneous combustion under inert gas environments: An experimental investigation

Comment: @Poutnik Why is that so? I want to model the dynamics of the reactions in a differential equation, and therefore I need rate constants for the dynamics of concentrations. Would you otherwise know some simplification or assumption for this?

Comment: The curse of solving differential equations is defining proper initial border and spatialconditions. Meteorologists could tell sagas about solving Richardson's partial diff. equations to predict synoptic situation by the most powerful available computers.

Comment: To get true rate constants from the rates, one has to know the true surface area and the true local boundary partial oxygen pressure across this area, which varies with local rates of mass transport. That leads rather to empirical, effective rate constants limited to particular scenarios. Even knowledge of the true rate constant would not be applicable for real scenarios due remaining unknowns.